# Angular $filter vs. manual filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using a filter with `ng-repeat` which does not filter my entries correctly. I have then analysed the problem and found out, that the filtering seems to differ.

The following two code samples doing comparable filtering. Code sample 1 gives wrong results, code sample 2 works as expected.

```
return $filter('filter')(courses, {courseCategory: {id: category.id}, active: active});
```

and

```
var courseList = [];
angular.forEach(courses, function (course) {
    if (course.courseCategory.id === category.id && course.active === active) {
        courseList.push(course);
    }
});

return courseList;
```

What is the difference of this two codes?

P.S.: The code I used in the `ng-repeat` was: `course in ctrl.courses | filter: {courseCategory: {id: category.id}, active: true}`. I think this is the equivalent to code sample 1.

Comment: Perhaps the value you're using in comparing to 'active' isn't the same. Is it a boolean or string? active: true vs course.active === active

Comment: It is a boolean value. Also the active parameter is in code sample 1 and 2 the same, but the result of both samples differ.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle with this being shown, with what you're looking for and what you're getting?